# How to programmatically specify the IP and port of a dependent docker container created by Marathon?

Tags: docker, microservices, mesos, marathon

I am learning Micro-services architecture by writing a small web app. The app has the following components, each of which will be hosted by a docker container.

[image]

In my API Gateway which is written in NodeJS, there is some place I will call:

```
request('http://service_b_ip_addr:port/get_service_b', callback);
```

However, both `service_b_ip_addr` and `port` are not known until Marathon has the Service B's docker container created.

With some Service Discovery mechanism, such as *mesos-dns* or *marathon-lb*, I guess that I could just change `service_b_ip_addr` to something like `service_b.marathon.com`.

But I've no idea how should I put the `port` in my program.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

PS:

1. I am using BRIDGED network mode given that multiple instances of a Service could locate on the same Mesos slave. So `port` is a NATted random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612).**

If you use marathon-lb then there is no need to pass a port because it's a proxy and it will know where service is just by name.

If you use mesos-dns you should make a SRV request to get ip and port. In node you can do it with [`dns.resolveSrv(hostname, callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvesrv_hostname_callback) but your DNS must be exposed on defaul (53) port and supports SRV request (mesos-dns supports it).