# Accessing microservices deployed on apache mesos agents

Tags: dns, load-balancing, microservices, mesos, marathon

How client can access a deployed microservice **without** specifing the host agent ip-address and the related mapping port.

If we add Mesos-DNS as the client resolver, we can only obtain agent ip-addresses but it doesn't return the list of  microservices instances and their related ports.

Supposed we have three instannces of webapp1 as follow:

```
+---------+---------+
| agent1  | agent2  |
+---------+---------+
|         |         |
| ins1:11 | ins3:13 |
|         |         |
| ins2:12 |         |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

client should be enabled to access one of instances directly (without referring agent1 and agent2 ip-addresses or those 11, 12 and 13 port numbers). For example:

```
$ lynx webapp1.marathon.mesos
```

Comment: Take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612)

DNS could provide information about servce port when you make [DNS SRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) request. It's not compatible with most of clients so you need to manually. Mesos DNS has [whole section dedicate to SRV records](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns/blob/1810c09811dfeb8c9e72ee6c58102313f74e0e1c/docs/docs/naming.md#srv-records)

Below is an example from docs:

> ### SRV Records
>
> An SRV record associates a service name to a hostname and an IP port.
>   For task `task` launched by framework `framework`, Mesos-DNS generates an SRV record for service name `_task._protocol.framework.domain`, where `protocol` is `udp` or `tcp`.
>   For example, other Mesos tasks can discover service `search` launched by the `marathon` framework with a lookup for lookup `_search._tcp.marathon.mesos`:

```
$ dig _search._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> _search._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33793
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_search._tcp.marathon.mesos.   IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_search._tcp.marathon.mesos.    60 IN SRV 0 0 31302 10.254.132.41.
```

> Mesos-DNS supports the use of a task's DiscoveryInfo for SRV record generation.
>   If no DiscoveryInfo is available then Mesos-DNS will fall back to those "ports" resources allocated for the task.
>   The following table illustrates the rules that govern SRV generation:

Answer (score 1):

Please check header `X-Marathon-App-Id` with marathon load balancer.

Example:

```
curl -v -H "X-Marathon-App-Id: /your-app-id-in-marahton" -X GET \
  http://marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:9091/yourAppEndPoint
```

More info [marathon-lb docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/marathon-lb/).

Comment: Question is about Mesos-DNS not marathon-lb