# Mesos/Marathon scalling a web application

Tags: nginx, mesos, marathon

I'm reading up and doing basic mesos/marathon installation. If Im deploying a webapp as a marathon application, the instance(s) of my webapp could run in any mesos slave. Howe would I then configure my nginx upstream to point to correct host(s).

Should my webapp register its host in zookeeper and reconfigure nginx periodically ?.

Is there any examples how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: [Nixy](https://github.com/martensson/nixy)  will do exactly what you want. You might be interested in whole topic of Discovery Service ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should my webapp register its host in zookeeper and reconfigure nginx periodically ?

You don't need zookeeper. All data required to configure nginx are available in Mesos or Marathon. You can periodically query Mesos/Marathon and generate Nginx configuration like [Nixy](https://github.com/martensson/nixy) does.

To minimize unavability time you can use Marathon SSE to get information about instances start/stop just like [allegro/marathon-consul](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-consul) does.