# Why containerPort and hostPort need to be same in DCOS?

Tags: azure, microservices, mesos, marathon, dcos

I have a web application with the below application definition and DCOS setup up and running on azure cloud with marathon-lb deployed. When I add below as a service.

```
{
  "id": "web",
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "myimage",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "hostPort": 5000, "containerPort": 5000, "servicePort": 0 }
      ],
      "forcePullImage":true
    }
  },
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 614,
  "labels":{
    "HAPROXY_GROUP":"external",
    "HAPROXY_0_VHOST":"localhost",
    "HAPROXY_0_MODE":"http"
  }
}
```

I am able to access my application through browser only when I keep containerPort and hostPort same.

If I change the hostPort to 0 , I am not able to access the app.
And I need hostPort as 0 so that I can scale the app and It will allocate the free hostPort to the application.
What is wrong here pls guide?

Answer (score 0):

`hostPort` equal to 0 means your application will be stared at random port assigned by Mesos. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612)

You don't need to keep `hostPort` and `containerPort` equal. `containerPort` must match the port application is listening at. `hostPort` might be any port (that's why you should use 0 for it). Containerizer will then pass packets sent to/from your `hostPost` to `containertPort` inside the container.