# mesos/dcos: Expose a service endpoint

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

When deploying a service on `kubernetes` that one wants to be publicly accessible, the way around is to declare its type as `LoadBalancer`

What is the equivalent way to expose a service endpoint on MESOS/DCOS?

Answer (score 1):

In DCOS there are 2 types of agents

1. Private (default)
2. Public

To run service that will be publicly available you need to run it on public agent. It can be done with `"acceptedResourceRoles":["slave_public"]`. For more information [see the docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/deploying-services/expose-service/).

---

In Mesos, you need to take care of your service. There are plenty solutions basic concepts are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822870/1387612)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to expose your service publicly:

1. Deploy your app on public node with below parameter in your marathon app definition :
   `"acceptedResourceRoles":["slave_public"]`
   It will tell mesos to run your app on public nodes.
   Then you can access your service using `<PUBLIC IP of public node>:<HOST_PORT>`
   You have to define host port in networking section of your app definition.
2. Deploy a marathon_lb on public node (available on Universe) and configure your app to be exposed via virtual host (By setting app labels : `HAPROXY_GROUP : external, HAPROXY_0_VHOST : <PUBLIC IP of your Public node>`)
3. Setup your own reverse proxy like haproxy and configure your app as backends.
4. If your app is a Mesos framework, it can register a webui_url for administrative access via the admin router.
   https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/development/dcos-integration/#framework-web-ui-url

   Add below labels in app definition:

   `"DCOS_SERVICE_NAME": "<service-name>",
   "DCOS_SERVICE_PORT_INDEX": "0",
   "DCOS_SERVICE_SCHEME": "http"`

Comment: I used the provided labels for Mesos framework and i am able to expose service but some how static data(.css) of service is not getting load