# Can you tell me the solution to the change of service ip in mesos + marathon combination?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I am currently posting a docker service with the MESOS + Marathon combination.

This means that the IP address of the docker is constantly changing.

For example, if you put mongodb on marathon, you would use the following code.
port can specify the port that is coming into the host. After a day, the service will automatically shut down and run and the IP will change.

So, when I was looking for a method called mesos dns, when I was studying the docker command, I learned how to find the ip of the service with the alias name by specifying the network alias in the docker.

I thought it would be easier to access without using mesos dns by using this method.

However, in marathon, docker service is executed in json format like below.
 I was asked because I do not know how to specify the docker network alias option or the keyword or method.

```
{
    "id": "mongodbTest",

    "instances": 1,

    "cpus": 2,

    "mem": 2048.0,

    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",

        "docker": {
            "image": "mongo:latest",

            "network": "BRIDGE",

            "portMappings": [

                {
                    "containerPort": 27017,

                    "hostPort": 0,

                    "servicePort": 0,

                    "protocol": "tcp"

                }

            ]

        },

        "volumes": [

            {
                "containerPath": "/etc/mesos-mg",

                "hostPath": "/var/data/mesos-mg",

                "mode": "RW"

            }

        ]

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run redis in marathon (mesos) under one url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811262/run-redis-in-marathon-mesos-under-one-url)